# Remove special characters from JSON output

Tags: java, json

How to remove  special character (In here '@') in the rest API output when converting to Java object.Because it is not allowed in java variables.

```
{ 
    "@id" : "1234" ,
    "dateTime" : "2022-05-27T10:15:00Z" ,
    "measure" : "abcd" ,
    "value" : 1.609
  }
```

Below object is not allowed:

```
private String @id;
 private String dateTime;
 private String measure;
 private float value;


 // Getter Methods 

 public String get @id() {
  return @id;
 }
```

Comment: Which JSON parser are you using?

Comment: use `@JsonProperty` to define the name of this property after mapping it to JSON (Jasckson mapper)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which JSON parser you're using, you can specify the JSON name for a given field. Here is an example for Jackson and GSON

```java
public class TestClass {
    @SerializedName("@id") // GSON
    @JsonProperty("@id") // Jackson
    private String id;
    private String dateTime;
    private String measure;
    private float value;
    
    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Comment: This might be a really stupid followup question but if the dateTime field also came in as `@dateTime` I'm assuming the same thing can be added right above the `private String dateTime;` line?

Comment: That's correct.